# How to prove syntactic consequence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a problem like this:

$$ F = \{A\sim B, B \sim C, ¬C∨B\} $$

And I want to check if this is true: $\{A∨C\}\vdash F$.

Comment: Since syntactic consequence $T\vdash \varphi$ means "there is a proof of $\varphi$ from $T$", the way you prove it is to provide a proof!

Comment: I just do not understand what is the "proof".

Comment: Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your question. Also, please provide some context: what have you tried and (in this case) what logical system are you working in. @AlexKruckman: your comment is to the point as ever, but somewhat nuanced here as $F$ appears to be a set of formulas $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Also, what does the $\sim$ symbol represent?

Comment: I mathjaxified the post and chose to render `~` as $\sim$. In my experience, `~` either means `not` or else it means `is equivalent to` in some sense. I suspect it means the latter here.

Comment: Please explain your question a little more thoroughly and show what you've tried so far. Explaining notation (like $\sim$ here) would also probably help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will assume for the purposes of this answer that $A \sim B$ means $\text{$A$ if and only if $B$}$.

I'm also going to assume that you want to show that the following is true when interpreted as a sequent.

$$ A \lor C \vdash A \leftrightarrow B, B \leftrightarrow C, \lnot C \lor B $$

Let's rewrite this slightly

$$ A \lor C, C \vdash A \leftrightarrow B, B \leftrightarrow C, B $$

This statement is not a tautology because if $A$ and $C$ are true, but $B$ is false, then all the premises are true, but the conclusion is false (in fact, all the disjuncts are false).